# Using GL Studio video in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My software guys are trying to figure out if it's possible to have video being generated by GL Studio (OpenGL) to display in game on a material.

In a nutshell, we have GL Studio creating videos for display units on the fly based on inputs from the user. We are trying to get that video that is being created to show up in game. Is there a way to grab that video that was being rendered in a window before and have a material display it in game instead?

Answer (score 0):

I havent heard of GL Studio being integrated into Unity this way.  Did you ask GL Studio support? support@disti.com

Cheers,

Jonathan